# Codeigniter error message Duplicate entry

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to implement Php Codeigniter model function that can count the number of left children and the number of right children for binary tree but i got this message error :

> Error Number: 1062
>
> Duplicate entry '4' for key 1 INSERT INTO 'mytable' (`members_id`,
>   `members_username`, `members_password`,)Filename:
>   C:\AppServ\www\app\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

i use this function and i think i have some logic error .

```
function count(){
 $query = $this->db->get('mytable');
foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
 if ($row->id > 1) {
  $Right_Child= $this->insert_to_right($row, $row->id);
  $Left_child = $this->insert_to_left($row, $row->id);
$count1=0;
    $count2=0;
if($Left_child!=NULL){

        for($count1;$count1<=10;$count1++)

            {
       $count1=$htis->Left_child->count();
            echo 'Left_child';

        }
        if($Right_Child!=NULL){
            for($count2;$count2<=10;$count2++){
            $count2= $this ->Right_Child->count();

            return $count2;
            echo 'Right_Child';
            if($count1==$count2){
                echo'tree';

            }

            }
        }
    }

        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to solve this error message & is this logic for counting number of child correct ?

Comment: hello, the problem is you've set UNIQUE key for ID (as should be, but you've forgotten set it to Auto Increment.)

Comment: I set it to Auto Increment and i got the same error .

Comment: the problem is when u insert the data.. check ur query for insert .. if u set auto increment to the primary key.. just let the value null for the `members_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Amin Adha has pointed out is correct.

When you INSERT a record into the database, try to leave out the ID of the record, or, set it to NULL.

In this case, the ID field appears to be "members_id"

You have a problem with an insert somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add auto increamt to member_id

```
 ALTER TABLE mytable ADD members_id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

Once remove old data and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If you using Integer for **id**, Try change your type field *member_id* from *int*->PRIMARY into *varchar*->PRIMARY, and dont use **Auto Increment** on your Database